# Add New Ringtones, Notifications and Alarm tones on Nexus One

Tags: nexus-one, ringtone, file-management

I have music (MP3 files) on my SD card and am trying to set them as ringtones, notification tones and alarm tones on my Nexus One.

My phone only lets me select the stock ringtones, notifications or alarms. I tried to transfer  and copy the music files to the ringtones and notification folder on my phone but it fails every time.  I think those folders are write protected or something.

Can anyone help? I have searched at all possible solutions online.  Some solutions suggest copying the files using my PC to my phone's ringtones/notification tones folder, but I can't even see these folders on Windows Explorer.  It's like they are invisible.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

There are special directories you can use to store your custom "noises". The "starting point" (root-of-noises-dir) may be different between devices (so this is rather a generic answer, as I do not own all of them) -- pick one and check if it works, if not, pick the next:

```
/sdcard/media/audio
/sdcard/media
/sdcard
```

In there, put the directories for the specific events:

```
┌───────────────┬───────────────────────┐
| directory     | description           |
├───────────────┼───────────────────────┤
| alarms        | for your alarm clock  |
| notifications | for... notifications? |
| ringtones     | for incoming calls    |
| ui            | keyboard click etc.   |
└───────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Then place your sound files into the appropriate directories. Done. Now you should be able to pick them in your configuration(s).

Answer (score 2):

The app [Rings Extended](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angryredplanet.android.rings_extended) combined with any [free file manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager&c=apps&price=1) will do what you want. Once installed, picking a ringtone will pop up a window asking which app to use for ringtone selection.  Tick the option to make it a default and choose "Rings Extended".  It will then allow you to pick any supported music file from your SD card for ring and notification tones.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I've installed it and it works perfectly. Exactly what I need without having to hack my phone...!

Comment: @dizzyhytes: If this answer really solved your problem, you should "accept" it so that future readers can benefit. Please see the [FAQ] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

I have had luck on CyanogenMod 6 by making a folder called "Ringtones" on my sd card and putting files there. However this may be CyanogenMod specific. (You may need to reboot or trigger the media scanner to get the files to show up.)

Comment: That's how I did it as well, and I'm not using Cyanogen, just the "pure" ICS of the Nexus S. Besides `Ringtones`, I created `Notifications` and `Alarms`. I believe this feature works on all Android devices.

Comment: I had assumed that such a simple but poorly documented feature was something the CM folks would do. ;)