# Transfer / Export or a specific notification ringtone

Tags: lg-optimus-one

My friend has a notification ringtone that I want on my phone but I can't find it on hers so I can send it to myself.  The ringtone came on her phone and is not on her SD card. Does anyone know how I can do this?  We both have the same LG android phone.  Or at least know where I can download it off the Internet.  It's simply called "POP" and goes something like "Ch'pow"   LOL.  Thanks

Comment: Those files are stored below `/system/media/audio`. Not sure if you can access this folder directly on a not-rooted phone. But maybe some media picker allows you to "share" the file via e.g. bluetooth?

Comment: Did that work out for you? If so, it might be useful if I convert my comment to a more detailed answer, so future "searchers" can easily see this issue has a solution.

Comment: @Izzy, it helped me. Add your comment as an answer and I'll upvote it. Please notify here in the comments or I'll forget!

Comment: @TylerCollier Done, including additional pointers :)

Answer (score 2):

Pre-installed ringtones can be found below `/system/media/audio` (see also [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56908/16575) for additional details). If you want to know where to place your custom ringtones on your device, take a look at [my other answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27740/16575).

Enjoy!