# How to change alarm sound to an MP3

Tags: alarm

I've tried creating an "alarms" folder on the root of my SD card on my Galaxy Note 3 (Jelly Bean 4.3) then unmounting and mounting it again. Didn't work. Tried an application (Tone Picker) to let me put the song as an alarm but still the song doesn't show up. When I select the song from Clock JB+, I can easily select the song with the File Manager app but the song won't be found when the alarm sounds then it will just sound the regular "beep" alarm

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add a few more details, such as device used and Android version running on it? Also, where *exactly* the sound file has been placed might be useful to know.

Comment: Thanks! You might wish to take a look at [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27740/16575), which hopefully gets you a step further.

Comment: In addition to Izzy's answer you can also change the file extension from '.mp3' to '.ogg'  with no problems. (not sure if that's what you're asking.)

Answer (score -3):

Get [Alarm Clock Xtreme Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free). There is also a paid version which removes the ads.