# Importing custom ringtone

Tags: ringtone

I have downloaded a ringtone and now would like to put it on the list of available ringtones on my Maxx2.  How do I put it on the ringtone list?  What is the proper format?  .wav, .aiff?

Comment: Related: [Add New Ringtones, Notifications and Alarm tones on Nexus One](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20712/16575)

Answer (score 1):

It simply done by having it as an mp3, which is to be put into either the "Ringtones" or "Notifications" folder (please do both to be sure) from the phone's internet storage. If one or both are not present, you can always make the folder yourself then place the files there. It should appear in the right settings menu that's right for it!

Comment: You can also use some apps from the Play Store which can help: a good one's this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.herman.ringtone